# How can I make my web application running on Windows Server access the network drive using Apache Tomcat?

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, windows-server-2016

I use Apache Tomcat as my web application services, and I installed service.bat .
when my application access the network drive I get this trouble.
firstly the applicaiton logs notice that I dont login, so I changed the server setting
that run the server on  administrator , it also cant access the network drive , but the logs notice that I need change account password before I login.

[this chinese mean that I need change account password befor i login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grTza.png)

I want my web application to access the network drive

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason. And remember that Stackoverflow is an English only site.

Comment: What kind of network drive is it? Mapped letter, UNC?